# Windows Phone - Set Image Source in Code

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone

I'm trying to set the image source in code. This is the current code and this works:

```
myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("1.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
```

But when I rewrite it as below, it won't work :

```
myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///1.jpg", UriKind.Absolute));
```

It's for a Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight app, and the image is stored in the project file. Any guidance suggesting what could be going wrong here is appreciated.

Comment: If the first thing works, why do you want to rewrite it?

Comment: Because I need to get absolute paths working for sourcing images from Local Storage on the phone. The above example is just to show how relative path works, but absolute doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff402541(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_Localfolder

> Local folder URI schemes
>
> Use the isostore or ms-appdata URI scheme names when addressing the local folder in a path. Although you can use both of these URI schemes to access the local folder, they cannot be used interchangeably. Use “ms-appdata:///local/” to address the root of the local folder with APIs that are in the Windows namespace. For all other APIs, use “isostore:/” to address the root of the local folder. The following code shows some examples of how to use these URI schemes.

```
// Create a local database in the local folder with the isostore URI scheme.
MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext("isostore:/mydb.sdf");

// Get a file from the local folder with the ms-appdata URI scheme.
var file = await Windows.StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/AppConfigSettings.xml"));
```